# Second layer in ggplot2 is shifted by one

Tags: r, layer, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a scatter-plot with two layers. The reason is I want to represent the size of the points by its number of answers. Then I need to have a smooth-curve layed over it. So I use two datasets to achieve this.
The problem is, when I lay the second layer with the smoother using the original dataset, then the smoother is shifted by one point on the x-scale to the left.

Does anyone know, how to correct this in the R code? Is there maybe something wrong in it? 
I thought about to add 1 to the x variable, but I don't want to have to go this far.

```
library(ggplot2)

q.tab <- xtabs(~x + y, mydata)
q.df <- as.data.frame(q.tab)
pointsize <- q.df$Freq
qplot(x, y, data=q.df) + geom_point(aes(size=as.factor(pointsize)))
+ geom_smooth(data=mydata, method="loess", span=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Please make this example reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

With ggplot2 , when you think in terms of layer it is better to use ggplot function and not qplot.

I generate your data (sample function is very convenient to generate data)

```
mydata$x <- sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE)
mydata$y <- sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE)
q.tab <- xtabs(~x + y, mydata)
q.df <- as.data.frame(q.tab)
```

ggplot version:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data=mydata,aes(x,y,size=Freq)) +
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth( method="loess", span=1)
```

qplot version:

```
qplot(data=mydata,x=x,y=y,size=Freq,geom='point')+
  geom_smooth( method="loess", span=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats why I need to use the original dataset: `ggplot(data=q.df, aes(ANQ01, A_Frage18, size=pointsize)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(data=ANQPPB, method="loess", span=1)`. But then I get: "Fehler: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:pointsize"

Comment: When I use your code: `ggplot(data=q.df, aes(x, y, size=pointsize)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="loess", span=1)` I get the error message: _"geom_smooth: Only one unique x value each group.Maybe you want aes(group = 1)?
Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : Argument has length 0"_